# Inserting a frame every n frames

Tags: beamer

I am using `beamer` for a presentation (of sorts) and want to add a frame every *n* frames (let's keep things general). As an additional challenge, I want these extra slides to *not* be counted in the regular numbering (although this is maybe better solved by using a custom counter? See below).

### What I've tried

I'm really close to getting this done, but my approach I guess can be improved.

What I've been trying so far is to use `everypage` to perform a check at every page to see if an extra slide should go after (I do this check using `pgf`), and if it is, I insert a frame with `afterpage`.

This *works*, but it adds one too many additional slides, because in a 10 page presentation it adds an extra one at the end (after page 10, which technically is not wrong, but is not what I want). Also, it means I need to add **two** packages, just for this (and that's just because I get `pgf` for free with `beamer`)!

Also, for this I've been using `framenumber`, but it's very possible that it would be better to use a different, custom counter (since `beamer`, you know... *uses* `framenumber`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{everypage}

% Regular slide
\newcommand{\baseslide}[1]{
  \begin{frame}{\phantom{bg}}
    \begin{center}%
      \LARGE #1
    \end{center}
  \end{frame}
}

% Extra slide
\newcommand{\extraslide}{
  \baseslide{This slide was inserted}
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
}

% Modulo test using pgfmathparse
% Based on http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15303/18982
\newcommand\modulo[4]{ 
  \begingroup
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{#2}
  \pgfmathparse{mod(\a,\b)==0} 
  \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt= 1 pt 
    #3
  \else 
    #4
  \fi 
  \endgroup
}

% At every page, check if the next should come before an inserted slide
\AddEverypageHook{
  \modulo{\value{framenumber}+1}{5}{
    % If so, add a slide after that page
    \afterpage{\extraslide}
  }{}
}

\begin{document}

\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
% Slide should go here
\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
\baseslide{This is test \insertframenumber}
% But it also goes here, and it shouldn't!

\end{document}
```

So, my questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. How can I make sure that these pages are only added *within* the document (not as the first or last page)?

### Additional, perhaps not necessarily useful background

I'm using beamer to generate a series of slides with some text that I can show to people one at a time to elicit certain responses. In this particular case, they are sentences to be read during a recording session.

The extra slides I'm inserting are "breaks", so that I can give the participant (performer?) some time to rest, drink some water, or do whatever it is people do when they relax.

Comment: Uncertain idea: Maybe you could add a counter to count the number of inserted slides, and add a test in `\modulo` to check if the considered page number is equal to the last page number (this requires of course two compilations) plus the number of inserted slides. If it is, you should not insert a blank frame, since it means the considered slide is the last one. Hope it gives you some ideas before more elegant solutions come.

Comment: You might find this [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187260/creating-static-numbered-sections-in-a-document) helpful. It describes a way of automatically inserting some predefined sections into particular places of a document (for example as sections 6, 9, 11).

Comment: That's a good idea, @anderstood. However, I've never written anything that relies on multiple compilations, so I don't really know how to take advantage of that. Any pointers?

Comment: @Andrew's suggestion is not bad either, but I'd have to mess with the definition of an environment instead of a command... and the placement issues would remain, no?

Comment: @jja: i'm sure you've already written many things which rely on multiple compilations: for ex. any references (to figures, sections, etc.) need to be compiled twice to work. Concretely, you just have to run pdflatex twice. Hope I'm not too unclear...

Comment: Let me add that my first thought was also to use pdftk! But as you said that's no the answer to your initial question :)

Comment: Instead of manipulating the `framenumber` counter by hand, you could use the `noframenumbering` option for the extra slides: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30461/3323

Comment: That sounds good, actually! Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

### A non-answer using `pdftk`

With the existing solution (the MWE), the last spurious slide (in the cases where it exists) can be easily removed with the help of `pdftk` (although this sort of post-production makes me feel dirty inside):

```
pdftk "input.pdf" cat 1-r2 output "output.pdf"
```

Another possibility would be to go with an entirely `pdftk` solution.

I put together this `bash` script which works fine... but it messes with the pagination (of course) in such a way that in a file which originally had 10 pages, in which you added the slide every 5 pages, the page that was originally page 6 will be now page 7 (and labeled as such) in the final pdf. The whole reason for me messing with `framenumber` in the first place was to keep the page numbering ignore the extra slides, so this is not really a solution in my book. But for completion's sake, here it is:

```
#/bin/bash

file=$1
every=$2
out=$3

added=$(mktemp PDFXXXX.pdf)
pages=$(
  echo "$(
    pdftk "$file" dump_data |
    grep NumberOfPages   |
    cut -f2 -d" "
  )-1" | bc -l
)
n=$(echo "($pages - 1) / $every" | bc)

pdftk "$file" cat end output "$added"
pdftk "$file" cat 1-r2 output "$out"

for ((i=$n;i>0;i--)); do
  start=$(echo "($i * $every) + 1" | bc)
  end=$(echo "$start - 1" | bc)
  tmp=$(mktemp PDFXXXX.pdf)

  pdftk A="$out" B="$added" cat A1-$end B1 A$start-end output "$tmp"
  mv "$tmp" "$out"
done
rm "$added"
```

Ran as `./script.sh "input.pdf" 5 "output.pdf"`, it will extract the last page of `input.pdf` and create a new `output.pdf` file in which this page is inserted every `5` pages in the original.

Answer (score 1):

The following example adds a slide *before* a new frame if needed.

- no additional frame at the beginning is ensured by `\ifnum\value{framenumber}=0`
- per construction an additional frame at the end is not possible

**Con's**

The additional frame has to use the `\frame{}` syntax and cannot be written as `\begin{frame}`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{
\ifnum\value{framenumber}=0
\else
    \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\value{framenumber},3))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
        \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
        \frame{%
            whatever
        } 
    \fi
\fi
}


\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,30} {
    \begin{frame}
        \insertframenumber
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```